# Get function from x64 instruction pointers?

Tags: linux, assembly, stack, x86-64, backtrace

This is an exercise that I want to implement in real code

I send a signal to my app (x86-64 linux). My app then executes code that walks the stack and prints out instruction pointers. I'm not sure if I want only the last few or everything to main. Anyway, I'm releasing an optimized binary without debug information. I strip symbols before its distributed.

I was wondering, how do I translate it back? I don't need to translate it in the app. I can use the machine I build to go from rip's to functions. I was thinking maybe I should also distribute one with debug information and maybe have the user be able to see the function+line but I think line will be unlikely if its optimized well

Another problem I have is my code doesn't seem to walk past the signal function. backtrace figures it out but I'm trying to do this without libc. Here's some code

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstdio>
typedef unsigned long long u64;
int mybacktrace();

#include <execinfo.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void print_stacktrace(void) {
    size_t size;
    enum Constexpr { MAX_SIZE = 1024 };
    void *array[MAX_SIZE];
    size = backtrace(array, MAX_SIZE);
    backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDOUT_FILENO);
}

void mysig(int signo) {
    mybacktrace();
    _exit(1);
}
int mybacktrace() {
    u64*p;
    p = (u64*)((u64)&p + 16); //seems to work correctly
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && (u64)p >= 1<<16; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %p\n", i, p[1]);
        p = (u64*)(p[0]);
    }
    print_stacktrace(); return 0;
    return 0;
}
int test()
{
    return mybacktrace();
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGILL, mysig);
    test();
    __builtin_trap();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either keep unwind info (`.eh_frame`) which isn't stripped by default, or build with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` so unwinding can use that simple algorithm.  You can have `strip` save the debug info to a separate file, which you might or might not distribute to users.  If not, you can still translate hex addresses in backtraces to symbolic, like how the Linux kernel does it for oops logs with `addr2line`.

Comment: @PeterCordes sounds good. I can't believe I spent the last hour looking at this not noticing your comment. I ended up doing no omit pointer but it seems like the one and only address I don't print out is the location of __builtin_trap(). The address doesn't appear to be in any registers or on the stack

Comment: `__builtin` functions aren't real functions, they inline, e.g. to a `ud2` instruction on x86-64. https://godbolt.org/z/v94q7Gbdv .  When it executes, it causes a #UD x86 exception (Illegal instruction trap), pushing an exception frame onto the *kernel* stack. The kernel delivers SIGILL to user-space.  At no point is there anything related to that fault address in user-space memory except for the arg to the signal-handler.

Comment: @PeterCordes I figured it out. sigaction with SA_SIGINFO, u->uc_mcontext.gregs[16]. Oh I meant I didn't print out the RIP of the trap function. I guess I should expect that is never pushed onto stack. I found it in what I'm assuming is 'general register' (gregs?)

Comment: `gregs` stands for "general purpose registers", yes, but they kind of bend the naming to include other integer but non-general-purpose registers into one array, instead of having other named members.  Probably makes it easier to loop over and copy.  https://codebrowser.dev/glibc/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86/sys/ucontext.h.html starts with an enum of the indices, and yeah, RIP is the first member after the actual GPRs, as index 16.  Then RFLAGS, segment selectors packed together, and some stuff including things that aren't even registers.